# Asp.net profile manager ignores daylight saving

Tags: asp.net, profile, dst

I have encountered a weird problem with asp.net profiles which is about the value in LastUpdatedDate column in aspnet_Porfile table of asp.net profiles and membership tables.

I am in a country with currently one hour daylight saving. The current time of my local machine is one hour behind what gets saved in the above column and I am totally working locally so there is no database or web server datetime coming through.

Have someone else experienced the same issue with asp.net profiles? It seems it ignores daylight saving settings.

Answer (score 2):

Most ASP.NET 'extras' use UTC which is not affected by DST.

[Datetime.ToLocalTime](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime) should do the conversion depending on how you create the Datetime you get from the DB